# Svelte #each not looping through data

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3

i'm taking SveleteJS for a test drive and got stuck

Made a `Dashboard` component and inside that component, i placed a Whiteboard component:

```
<script>
    import Whiteboard from "./Whiteboard.svelte";
    export let name;
</script>

<div class="box part-of-dashboard">
    <Whiteboard lines={[]} />
</div>
```

`Whitebord.svelte`:

```
<script>
    export let lines = [];

    export function addLine() {
        lines.push("blah");
        console.log(lines);
    }

</script>

<div style="background-color:red">
    {#each lines as line}
        <div>
            {line}
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
<div>
    <button on:click={addLine}>
        Add Line
    </button>
</div>
```

When i click the button, the `console.log` triggers and i can see the lines increasing in size, but i don't see it being rendered on the page, just the empty red div wrapping it.

I've tried adding `$:` to various places, but i'm not yet sure where it should be used and where it shouldn't be used, not that it was making a difference.

How do i get that #each to render a list of divs (and also, what is the correct way to pass in data from the `on:click`, doing {addLine('blah')} executes that addLine on page load)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, this kind of goes against what one might expect, but Svelte does not detect `[].push()` as mutating the state of the array variable. This is why the console log shows the variable being updated, but Svelte's rendering does not respond.

After doing a little digging, I found several threads ([1](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2362), [2](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3487)) that point this out, and clarify that this is true for calling methods on any object.

EDIT: This is also now called out explicitly in the docs / tutorials - see ["Updating Arrays and Objects"](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects)

One of the easiest solutions (per the linked threads and docs) is to simply re-assign the variable value to itself; Svelte will pick that up and re-render. So, in your scenario, all I had to do to get your code to work was replace this:

```js
export function addLine() {
    lines.push("blah");
    console.log(lines);
}
```

With:

```js
export function addLine() {
    lines.push("blah");
    lines = lines;
    console.log(lines);
}
```

Comment: That makes total sense, for change detection to pick up the changes, a pointer needs to  change. This might be cleaner then: `lines = lines.concat("blah");`

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert Good point, and yes, I think that looks good. Or a lot of people use the spread operator (`lines = [...lines, "blah"]`), or slice after the push (`lines = lines.slice()`). But concat is probably the fastest and cleanest one-line approach here.

Comment: See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects for more info

Comment: This was a very helpful answer, thank you. They SHOULD highlight this issue more in their intro docs!

Comment: Thank you this was driving me crazy

Comment: You can also use the spread syntax: `lines = [...lines, "blah"]`